# Change AWS Lambda python timezone

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, timezone

I used Python on AWS Lambda, but I can't find a way to change Timezone.
I've already used it,

```
os.environ['TZ'] = 'xxxxx'
```

But It didn't work.

How can I change the timezone at AWS Lambda with Python?

Comment: _Why_ do you wish to change the timezone? It is generally recommended to run systems on UTC so that logging is synchronized across all systems. Python has libraries to assist with converting a given timestamp between timezones. What is your particular need for changing the timezone at the operating-system level?

Answer (score 2):

To update the timezone in Python you have to call `time.tzset()`.

```
os.putenv('TZ', 'Asia/Tokyo')
time.tzset()
print(datetime.datetime.now())
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the timezone by specifying the `TZ` environment variable as part of the lambda configuration.

AWS has disabled being able to change the TZ env var during lambda invocation such that it is respected when calling python standard library functions. (You can set the variable with `os.putenv("TZ", "xxxxx")`, but it won't do anything)

The docs list `TZ` [as a reserved environment variable](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-envvars.html), giving the reason that "The execution environment uses NTP to synchronize the system clock."

Comment: I was able to set the TZ environment variable in the lambda configuration and have the timezone change in dot net code. Setting it in the lambda config ahead of time worked great.